# Why i am not getting the subtotal of rows

Tags: pandas, crosstab, subtotal

I am trying to get subtotal using pandas pivoting. I don't know why i am getting only column subtotal?

```
    data = {'TypeOfInvestor':['Stocks', 'Bonds', 'Real Estate'],
            'InvestorA': [96, 181, 88],
           'InvestorB': [185, 3, 152],
           'InvestorC': [39, 29, 142]}
```

```
      df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
    pt = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['InvestorA', 'InvestorB', 'InvestorC'],
                        index=['TypeOfInvestor'],
                   aggfunc=np.sum, margins=True, margins_name='Total')
```

I expect to get subtotal of columns and subtotal of rows using pivot_table, but i am getting only subtotal of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this fairly easy by using `.sum` with `axis=1`:

```
pt['Total']= pt.sum(axis=1)

print(pt)
                InvestorA  InvestorB  InvestorC  Total
TypeOfInvestor                                        
Bonds                 181          3         29    213
Real Estate            88        152        142    382
Stocks                 96        185         39    320
Total                 365        340        210    915
```

Comment: Thank you @Erfan I will accept the answer because it's getting the job done but i don't understand why there is only column subtotal for this type of dataset when using pandas pivot.